# Android studio 3.6.1 gradle sync too slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

first I'm sorry my English is poor.

### Android Studio version:

Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 27, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 4029M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: CMD Support, ch.dasoft.iconviewer, com.dengzii.plugin.adb, com.sburlyaev.terminal.plugin, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, net.vektah.codeglance, org.intellij.plugins.markdown, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.longforus.kotlincodesorter, BashSupport, com.developerphil.adbidea, com.longforus.mvpautocodeplus, Dart, cn.yiiguxing.plugin.translate, io.flutter, com.ruiyu.ruiyu, wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin

### gradle Version:

gradle-6.1.1

### plugin version:

com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1

since update android studio version to 3.6+,i found that every time sync my project,Both search and download locally existing jars from the maven repository,it too slow,I waste a few minutes at a time,how to solve it? Thanks for watching

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug ,on android studio 3.6.2 google already fix it：
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149045341